# Succinct proof that $\frac\pi4+\frac\pi6+\log2\gt2$

Tags: inequality, definite-integrals, approximation, pi, rational-functions

In answering [Average angle between two randomly chosen vectors in a unit square](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3629474), I noticed that the average angle formed by two vectors uniformly picked in the unit square, $\frac\pi4+\log2-1\approx0.4785$, and the average angle formed by two vectors uniformly picked in the first quadrant of the unit disk, $\frac\pi6\approx0.5236$, add up to just a bit more than $1$ (about $1.0021$), that is, that

$$
\frac\pi4+\frac\pi6+\log2\gtrsim2\;.
$$

I thought it would be interesting to try to prove this with as little numerics as possible. Of course you can use sufficiently good rational approximations for $\pi$ and $\log2$, like I did to answer [Prove that $e^\pi+\frac{1}{\pi} < \pi^e+1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3558810), but I’d prefer a proof that shows directly that $\frac\pi4+\frac\pi6+\log2-2$ is a positive quantity, e.g. the integral over a positive function, as in [Is there an integral that proves $\pi > 333/106$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1956).

Answer (score 12):

I originally just wanted to ask the question and didn’t expect to find an answer myself, but playing around with the exponents in

$$
\int_0^1\frac{x^4(1-x)^4}{x^2+1}\mathrm dx=\frac{22}7-\pi
$$

I happened upon

$$
\int_0^1\frac{x^5(1-x)^4}{\left(x^2+1\right)^2}\mathrm dx=\pi+6\log2-\frac{73}{10}\;,
$$

which is exactly the sort of thing we need. Together with

$$
\int_0^1\frac{x^2(1-x)^4}{x^2+1}\mathrm dx=\pi-\frac{47}{15}
$$

(see [Integrals for semiconvergent approximations to $\pi$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2488985)), this yields

\begin{eqnarray}
\frac16\int_0^1\frac{x^5(1-x)^4}{\left(x^2+1\right)^2}+\frac14\int_0^1\frac{x^2(1-x)^4}{x^2+1}\mathrm dx
&=&
\frac1{12}\int_0^1\frac{\left(2x^3+3x^2+3\right)x^2(1-x)^4}{\left(x^2+1\right)^2}\mathrm dx
\\
&=&
\frac\pi4+\frac\pi6+\log2-2\;.
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: Neat! (Although I'm not supposed to write it)

Comment: nice ${}{}{}{}$