# Average angle in a square

Tags: probability-distributions

Consider a  unit square  $OABC$ where,$O\equiv (0,0),A \equiv (1,0),B \equiv (1,1), C \equiv ()$.If  two point $P_1$  and  $ P_2$is chosen randomly and uniformly  in or on the square.how do we find the expected value of  angle $\angle P_1OP_2$?
**My Attempt:-** If $(X_1,Y_1)$  and   $(X_2,Y_2)$ are the coordinates of the point chosen , Then ezch of the  x and y coordiantes follows  a uniform distribution in $(0,1)$  .If $\theta $ be the angle $\angle P_1OP_2$ ,then
$$ cos( \theta) =\frac{x_1x_2+y_1y_2}{\sqrt{{(x_1^2+y_1^2)}{(x_2^2+y_2^2)}}}$$. The goal ,then , is to find the pdf of  $\theta$.Thanks for any responses/hints in advance

Comment: Similar problem https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3629474/average-angle-between-two-randomly-chosen-vectors-in-a-unit-square

Comment: Instead of looking at pdf of angle between them find pdf of angle $\theta$ (with x axis) for any random point first. You will have to consider at $0 \leq \theta \leq \pi/4$ and $\pi/4 \leq \theta \leq \pi/2$ separately.